# Writing a beginner level encryption program on Python 3 (From Think Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

def doppelt(word):

```
word = word.lower()
encoded = ''
for c in word:
    new_ord = word
    new_ord = 96 + (new_ord - 121) % 26
    encoded += chr(new_ord)
return encoded
```

---

TypeError
         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

----> 1 doppelt('string')

in doppelt(word)
      4     new_ord = word
      5     for c in word:
----> 6         new_ord = 96 + (new_ord - 121) % 26
      7         encoded += chr(new_ord)
      8     return encoded

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your character to integer by

```
ord(c)
```

so the loop will look like this

```
for c in word:
    new_ord = ord(c)
    new_ord = 96 + (new_ord - 121) % 26
    encoded += chr(new_ord)
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition of an Integer with a String or Char raises the `TypeError` exception in Python.

So you first need to convert your `new_ord` to a integer first, before adding. You, can do this by the `ord()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform `-` operation (substraction) between a number (type: `int`) and a character (type: `str`).

For instance in

```
... new_ord - 121 ...
```

What you need to do is to first convert the character in to its equivalent integer using the in-built function `ord` which does just that.

See link: https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord

SIDENOTE:

in line 4

```
   new_ord = word
```

I think it should actually be `new_ord = c`, which now become `new_ord = ord(c)`.